# Objects are not valid as a React child, can't assign the API into array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

[image]

This is the output while logging the raw data.

[image]

and this is the output while logging the array after assigning.

So I have this problem. I try to fetch API (object, not array) file into my React code, but while assigning the data to the const it is returning empty array, but if I `console.log` the data before assigning it to const it is returning normally the file as it should. Can someone help me?

This is my code:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import useToggle from '../hooks/useToggle'
//import devices from '../import/devices.js'
//import pl_desc from "../import/pl_desc.json"
import axios, * as others from 'axios';

function App() {

  const Url = "http://localhost:8080/"
  const[click,clickChange] = useToggle("");
  const [data,setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(()=>{
      const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await fetch(Url, {mode:'cors'});
      const parsed = await result.json();
      console.log(parsed)
      //setData(parsed)
    }

      fetchData();

    },[])

    

  function handleEvent(event){
      clickChange(click,event);
    };
  return (      
    <>
                  
      {click == true ? (
        <div className="menu">
          <button
          className='exit'
          onClick={handleEvent}
          ><img src='./svg/exit.svg'/></button>
          <input type='text'
          className='search'
          ></input>
              <ul>
              {data}
            </ul>  
        </div>
      ):(
        <button
        className='guzik'
        onClick={handleEvent}
        ><img src='./svg/button.svg'/></button>
      )
      }

    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Can you please clarify the exact problem? .... Coz in your subject you mentioned there is an error... but in description, it looks like the array is coming as empty. For the latter one, why you have commented setData(parsed)?

Comment: It is supposed to be returning an array with elements so i can use that later in the code to map elements but its returning empty array. For the commented line i had to be doing something with that during posting the question so dont worry about that cause normally its not commented

Comment: Your raw data is an object and not an array. So when you assign it to data and do `{data}` you get the error about "Objects are not valid as a React child"